# importing of speech recognition is giving error in Python3.10.0

Tags: python

**CODE**

```
import pyttsx3 
import datetime 
import speech_recognition as sr
import wikipedia
```

**OUTPUT**

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
```

I am using Python3.10.0, Windows 11, and IDLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not actually ask a question.  For an answer to the implied 'Why?', read the doc for the [import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).  In summary, there is no `speech-recognition` located in the current working directory, nor in `Lib/site-packages` for the python binary you are running.

For more, search the `python` tag for [ModuleNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%20ModuleNotFoundError) and read some of the duplicate answered questions.